# Sending UDP packets to a destination

Tags: udp, packet

On my Linux machine, I am receiving UDP packets from another machine. When I receive the UDP packets, I get the message

```
"Listening on UDP port : 8999"
```

This is triggered by the following command part of a code that listens on that specific port.

```
GET_PORT((&(paraThread->destHost)), tmpPort);
fprintf(stderr, "Listening on UDP port : %d\n", ntohs(tmpPort));
```

What I need is that as soon as I receive every UDP packet, I need to send a response UDP packet of say 400 bytes to the IP address from which I received the UDP packet.
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: This is a strange request and I can assure you that as soon as a hacker finds out you do that, your machine will become used to attack other targets.  UDP spoofing is very easy to do.

Comment: You're trying to re-invent [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking).

Answer (score 0):

You can `cat` 400 bytes to the remote host when you receive the message :

```
cat 400bytes.txt >/dev/udp/remotehost/8000
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696129/how-to-send-only-one-udp-packet-with-netcat).
Many other options are available of course.

To generate 400 random bytes to that device, use `dd` :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=400 of=/dev/udp/remotehost/8000
```

Comment: should I replace remotehost with the IP address?

Comment: @AshishKurian: of course.

Comment: so I should also create a text file named 400bytes.text ? Is there a way to send some random 400 byte payload

Comment: yes there is, i'll add that to my answer

Comment: ‘dd’ was not declared in this scope. I am getting this error when I compile the code

Comment: well. what are you using to send the reply ? `dd` is a command located at `/bin/dd`, the commands I wrote can be run in `bash ` for ex.

Comment: mazs, I am adding that in the code and then compiling. I am not using it in bash.    http://www.grid.unina.it/software/ITG/  this is the package that I want to use

Comment: well, use `fprintf` to the '/dev/udp/remotehost/8000' and print 400 bytes for example. these kind of questions belong to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: The answer in for `bash`  the question looks like C (though does not state a language). This question belongs on stack overflow, as it is about programming.